# Laravel 5.2 subdomain routing, depending on user role.

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have some problems with subdomain routing in laravel 5.2 and hope you can help me with it.

The point is that I need to redirect a user on certain subdomain, depending on it's usertype.

For example in database I have a usertype (1,2,3 etc...) and basing on that value I need to redirect user on

```
type1.mysite.com
type2.mysite.com
type3.mysite.com
```

etc...
But the problem is that I can't get authenticated user in `routes.php`, it always returns null.
Any ideas on how to solve that problem?

And by the way, to make a subdomain routing, I have to configure apache in some way or it can be done with laravel?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to edit it and specify what we want it to do.
In App\Http\Middleware you should see the newly created file
php artisan make:middleware UserTypeMiddleware

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class UserTypeMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //check your user type here 
        if ($request->user()->type != 1)
        {
            return redirect('DefinedRoute');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Got it. And what about routing to a certain subdomain? Do I need to configure apache?

Comment: you need to configure apache2 for this point , this link will help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-create-a-subdomain-in-apache-ubuntu-14-04